# synchronize video output on HDMI 1 and HDMI 2 on a Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: multithreading, hdmi, omxplayer

I am trying to play a video using omxplayer (but I could use a different player to solve the problem) on both HDMI outputs of a Raspberry PI 4 but without much success. Until now I tryed starting 2 processes or threads but the output is not synchronized. The test code is quite simple: it starts 2 processes (or 2 threads) calling a Python wrapper ove omxplayer, both load the video and put it on pause, then I send to both processes the play command but there is a delay between the command reception and the start of the video on the second process/thread. So, any idea or help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem and the solution. I created a simple Python wrapper for omxplayer that when creates the process executing omxplayer puts omxplayer in pause sending the toggle_pause command, but if I pass the --no-keys argument to omxplayer it starts without any regard about the toggle_pause command so the 2 processes are not in sync. The solution is very simple: do not use the --no-keys argument...